# How do I cap the slider so that my next and prev buttons don't scroll past the content into whitespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/q4haaey6/) to demonstrate my question. If you continue to hit prev and next the slider bar keeps sliding even past the content.

```
$('#next').click(function() {
          $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
          }, "fast");
       });
$('#prev').click(function() {
      $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");
   });
```

I assume I need an if statement something like

```
if (current.width+totalScrolled < slider.width)
{
      $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
        marginLeft: "+=200px"
      }, "fast");
}
else
{
     [soemthing like set.scrollRight = max]
}
```

and again to keep track of where you are so you don't scroll back too far.

Even a solution that brings you back to the beginning would be a great way to solve this. I just help with logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the required if statements:

```
$('#next').click(function() {
    if($('#sliderWrapper').css("margin-left").replace("px", "")*-1 < $("#imageSlider").width()){
        $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=200px"
        }, "fast");
    }
});
$('#prev').click(function() {
    if($('#sliderWrapper').css("margin-left").replace("px", "") < 0){
        $('#sliderWrapper').animate({
            marginLeft: "+=200px"
        }, "fast");
    }
});
```

I also made some improvements to the css. At least, I think they are improvements, feel free to ignore them. The can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q4haaey6/16/). Set the width of the slider to anyting, I just set it to 400px for testing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Unfortunately it's not working entirely correctly, almost though! It only works until a certain point and then will not allow me to scroll anymore. I have your solution implemented [here](http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html).

Comment: More than! Your solution is cleaner code and works perfectly. I was previously having a problem where my fixed position previous and next buttons would overlap another div and that has been fixed by the way you've laid it out. I really appreciate the time.

Comment: No problem, it was fun! I like sliders.

Comment: I was hoping you could give me some more help on this slider. I'm trying to get the items to come into view when clicking a button- [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/p96wrtop/). I got the idea from (conveniently) your post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313267/get-page-to-slide-right-or-left-depending-on-where-the-user-clicked/25314982#25314982).

Comment: I do not understand the request.

Comment: Sorry! If you look [here](http://www.northerntechnomics.com/lmantzel/googlemap/maptest12.html) I'm hoping when you click on a marker on the map that the corresponding image will come into view on my slider bar at the bottom. Like automatically scroll to show the image on the slider. In my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/linddss/p96wrtop/) I try to use the button to bring the 5th image into view by changing the offset of the that image. It wasn't working though.

Comment: This is set up to scroll to the image number of the id of the clicked button. It require a set width on .thumbnail. http://jsfiddle.net/p96wrtop/3/

Comment: No problem. I am working on a lot of mysql right now so anything jQuery-ish to give me a break is great.